# Get _id when template event is trigger inside {{#each array}} block

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hi I'm trying to get the `_id` attribute value when `click` event is triggered in this template, if I click an element inside the `#each` block, the `_id` attribute is undefined. If I do the same with an element outside `#each` block, the correct `_id` is shown.

```
  <template name="main"> 
            <div class="clickable"> if click here you can get de _id value</div>
            {{#each array}}
               <div class="clickable"> if click here you can't get de _id value</div>       
            {{/each}}         
  </template>
```

I'm using this javascript code to access `_id` attribute

```
Template.main.events(
{
      'click .clickable'  : function (event, template)
      {
          console.log(this._id);
      }       
}
```

Can I access to the `_id` from an element created inside the `#each` block somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use template.data._id :

```
Template.main.events({
    'click .clickable': function(event, template) {
        console.log(template.data._id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `data` attributes:

```
<template name="main"> 
    <div class="clickable" data-id="{{_id}}">Click</div>
    {{#each array}}
        <div class="clickable" data-id="{{_id}}">Click</div>       
    {{/each}}         
</template>



Template.main.events({
    'click .clickable': function(event, template) {
        console.log($(event.target).data('id'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remove first clickable div object.